# EKReminder with RecurrenceRules

Tags: ios, swift, ekevent, ekeventstore, ekreminder

I was work on fetching reminder, I have no problem fetching title, last modified date, notes, etc but I only have problem is recurrenceRules. Here my code:

```
print(get_reminder_detail.recurrenceRules)
```

And when I ran the app, it said:

> [EKRecurrenceRule <0x28051c1e0> RRULE FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=1;UNTIL=20200815T061923Z]

As I see two things I am not sure how to pull information from this...first, how can I take FREQ  and INTERVAL into the string? Second, how can I pull the UNTIL into the DateComponents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not look at the string that is used to print out the recurrence rule in the console. Look at the properties of the recurrence rule itself.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit/ekrecurrencerule

Everything you need is right there.

Answer (score 1):

I just realized it, I found the resolved. Here the codes:

```
if let getrecurrence = get_reminder_detail.recurrenceRules?.first {
   if getrecurrence.frequency == .daily {print("Daily!")}
   if getrecurrence.frequency == .monthly {print("Monthly!")}
   if getrecurrence.frequency == .weekly {print("Weekly!")}
   if getrecurrence.frequency == .yearly {print("Yearly!")}
}
```

I guess I ask question too early